# How to include nested associations in JSON after creating an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, serialization, rendering

A Squad has many Players. If I try to create a new squad, it's ok but it doesn't return JSON with includeded players in the console.

This is my code at controller for create def:

```
def create
  squad = Squad.create(squad_params)
  render json: squad
end
```

And this is my serializer at model :

```
def serializable_hash(opts)
  super(opts.merge(only: [:id, :name, :user_id], include: :players))
end
```

And this is my returning json at console:

```
{id: 26, name: "gol", user_id: 1, players: Array(0)}
id: 26
name: "gol"
players: []
user_id: 1
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see, players array is empty. Actually it is not empty but it seems like empty at console.

I tried something like that with `include(:players)`, but it didn't work:

```
def create
  squad = Squad.create(squad_params)
  render json: squad.include(:players)
end
```

Do you know how to render squad json included player at create methods?

Comment: Does the `squad` have already players associated when is created?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes sure. Squads has_many: players and players belongs_to:squad. And I don't have any problem for creating new squad. I just need to add something rails controller. Now I have render json:squad at controller, it's working well but I just need to add something like json:squad.include(players) but I don't know how to do that with correct syntax.

Comment: Yes, I got it. But you want to return the squad and all their associated players from the create action, no? If so, when you create a new squad, does it have associated players, already? If so, try just with `squad.as_json(include: :players)`.

Comment: I tried like this:    `def create
        squad = Squad.create(squad_params)
        squad.as_json(include: :players)  ` but didn't return even data it's empty. It's creating a new squad with players but after creating a squad, i need to catch players at console. If i say only render :squad returns a data but without players. But there are players associated with squad. Just I need to show them as a json. I hope I could explain myself clearly.

Comment: Did you intentionally remove the `render json: ` part or just didn't copy it into the comment? Try that in the console.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I tried both with render json: or without render json: but unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for including relation in rails response is

```
render json: squad, include: :players
```

and make squad has players when it is created

Comment: I tried, it returns data but without players. players array return empty but normally it's not empty. It's incredible but didn't work.

Comment: @ci1991
Try use the `rails c` for console then `Squad.all` then select some of squad to make sure there is a players contain in it or try check the databases one.

Comment: I tried yes squad has players at rails c. I think the problem is squad has_many :players through: :playersquads maybe that's why I can't get directly players but I can see players array in the console, it just returns empty.